# How to use Response.AppendHeader to cue up players in a browser game?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, browser, response

```
Response.AppendHeader("Refresh","10; URL = game.aspx");
```

This code above will refresh the page every 10 seconds. Picture player 1 pressed the join button and be placed in a cue to wait for player two. How can I manipulate this code to ask for player two's input(joining), every ten seconds. Then when player two answers, it will transfer me to the game page using Server.Transfer.

I'm using Visual Studio '08, running ASP.NET websites and forms in C#.

Comment: You should use AJAX for this type of thing as opposed to refreshing the page. AJAX will selectively update elements within the page, as opposed to reloading the entire page which is probably unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage two boolean variables in memory , if player one is in make first true, check first variable after every 10 second (you are doing refresh after 10 seconds already). another side , if player two accepts/in make second variable true. Thus within 10 seconds variable becomes true first player will be redirected to game page.

Now the problem is where to store these two variables so that both user can share this. you can store it on server memory or in Application State.

Let me know if I am missing something.